# Can't play video streaming when call videoview.seekTo() in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview

I have an online video that is 1 hour long but when I use videoview.seekTo ()with seekbar , the video can not play. this is my source code

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0HkE.png)

[error when call videoview.seekTo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yg9M.png)